# The shuffle algebra over the rationals is isomorphic to the polynomial algebra in the Lyndon words

Tags: reference-request, hopf-algebras, symmetric-algebras, combinatorial-hopf-algebras, lyndon-words

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffle_algebra) wikipedia page is stated that over the rational numbers,  the shuffle algebra (over a set $X$) is isomorphic to the polynomial algebra in the Lyndon words (on $X$). I was wondering if you can show me a proof of this or give me a reference. Ideally I am looking for an explicit isomorphism between these two algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proven in Theorem 6.3.4 of [Hopf Algebras in Combinatorics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8356)
 by Grinberg and Reiner.

They call it "Radford’s theorem on the shuffle algebra" citing Theorem 3.1.1(e) of [A natural ring basis for the shuffle algebra and an application to group schemes](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(79)90171-6) by Radford where you can find another proof.